# Spring/Junit accessing a sibling class

Tags: java, spring, testing, maven, junit

Running my my Test class

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:eq-mo-dcc-context-block.xml"})

public class SpringTest {

@Autowired
private DateUtils dateManager;

@Autowired
private RegionFilter filter;

@Autowired
private ApplicationContext appContext;

@Test
public void test_This()
{
    Object obj = appContext.getBean("BlockTransformer");
    BlockTransformer Trans = (BlockTransformer) obj;


}
```

All very early stages however the problem that arises the configuration file accesses beans from other Maven modules/Projects. However I have all the xml under src/test/resources, so it can pick up the xml. However the when trying to pick up the class files I get:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [dcc.mdp.DefaultMessageListener] for bean with name 'BlockMessageListener' defined in class path resource [eq-mo-dcc-context-block.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: dcc.mdp.DefaultMessageListener
```

This class resides in a sibling maven module, yet cannot be picked up from the test class. How can the class be made aware of classes from other modules other than it's own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Maven module doesn't automatically "know" anything about other modules under the same parent project, so the sibling module containing the classes you want needs to be listed as a dependency in the module containing your test class.

Comment: You need to explicitly define dependencies to run this test suite.